# Location of Blackberry code-signing "previous Blackberry Java Development installation directory" in Import Existing Keys (Eclipse BB plugin)

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I need to sign the code of my BB application for an update but I've changed computers and I just have a copy of all the files on the previous one's hard drive. When I try to "Import Existing Keys" in the Eclipse BB plugin I am prompted to "select previous BlackBerry Java Development installation directory." To which directory is this prompt referring and where might I find it (where is it placed by default?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you originally install code signing keys from RIM, and use them, the toolset will generate three files:

```
sigtool.csk
sigtool.db
sigtool.set (maybe not needed?)
```

These are the files that Eclipse wants.

So, you could just use Windows explorer (or Mac equivalent if on OS X) to search for the folder that has those files.

Depending on your situation, it could be in different places.  It could be in the user's .eclipse directory:

```
C:\Users\myname\.eclipse\
```

Or, it could be under the BlackBerry JDE / Eclipse plugin installation directory.  For example,

```
C:\Eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack5.0.0_5.0.0.36\components\bin
```

For completeness, I'll dig up a couple old computers, and see where they have the code signing files installed, but for your purposes, doing a filesearch for `*.csk` is probably the easiest way to go.

### Reference

[Backup and Restore BlackBerry Code Signing Keys](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/Backup-and-Restore-BlackBerry-Code-Signing-Keys/ta-p/837925) :

> The files that need to be backed up are sigtool.csk and sigtool.db and
>   are located in the directories outlined below.  Their location will
>   vary based on the tool used to install them.  All paths below are
>   relative to the tool's installation directory.  To restore or enable
>   your code signing keys in another application, copy the sigtool.csk
>   and sigtool.db to the directories outlined below.
>
> - BlackBerry® Java® Plug-in for Eclipse®: 
>     `.\Eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde\vmTools`
> - BlackBerry® Java® Development Environment (BlackBerry  JDE):  `.\BlackBerry JDE #.#.#\bin`
> - BlackBerry® WebWorks™ SDK:  `.\BlackBerry WebWorks Packager\bin`